# trailing comma in assigning argument parameter in 'sched.scheduler.enter'

Tags: python, tuples

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc): 
    print("Doing stuff...")
    s.enter(5, 1, do_something, argument=(sc,))

s.enter(5, 1, do_something, argument=(s,))
s.run()
```

In this code bit, I am using sched lib to create a function loop. Here I noticed that when we are assigning an argument, there is a trailing comma. I am wondering why is that?

When I delete the trailing comma, it returns error says:

> do_something() argument after * must be an iterable, not scheduler

In other trailing comma questions, people said trailing comma will turns int into a tuple. Here, when I add the trailing comma or not, the value type of `s` is still scheduler object.

Comment: `(s)` is same as `s` while `(s,)` is a tuple containing the one item referred to by variable `s`. It has nothing to do with `int` in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples only need `,` commas, they don't need `()` parenthesis, except when they do!  So for example in:

```
x = 1, 2, 3
y = (1, 2, 3)
```

And:

```
x = 1,
y = (1,)
```

In both cases `x` and `y` are identical.  But in your case:

```
s.enter(5, 1, do_something, argument=(sc,))
s.enter(5, 1, do_something, argument=sc,)
```

Are, as you found out, not the same.  Why?

Well in the second case `argument=sc,` the `,` is interpreted to be part of the `,`'s of the parameter list, so it is not considered as indicating a `tuple()`.  And in this case, you need the `(sc,)` to build a `tuple()`

Comment: Great explanation of a very common corner case in tuple construction.